# Testing Custom Validate Action for Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I've got a custom action to validate the number of child attributes. I've put this in the parent's model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blacklisted
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blacklisted, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:mac].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true  
  ...
  validate :check_blacklisted_clients_count

  private

  def check_blacklisted_clients_count
    if self.blacklisted.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).count > 25
      self.errors.add :base, "No more than 25 blacklisted clients allowed per location."
    end
  end
```

That works fine when I add through the browser however I'm trying to test this with rspec and I can't get it to fail (or pass, whichever way you look at it).

```
  it "should not allow 26 blacklisted macs", :focus => true do 
    loc = FactoryGirl.create(:location_full)
    25.times do
      loc.blacklisted.create(mac: '00:22:33:44:55:66')
    end
    loc.blacklisted.create(mac: '00:22:33:44:55:66')
    puts loc.blacklisted.count
    .........

  end
```

(I know that doesn't actually test anything yet - I just wanted to make sure only 25 are created).

I'm assuming this is because there's no validation in the blacklisted.rb model.

How can I get rspec to test this validation?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach is to write one spec that adds fewer than 25 blacklisted MACs, and another one that adds more than 25, and test that the former is valid and the latter is invalid.

Depending on how you feel about spec runtimes, that might work out just fine. If the test is too slow, you might want use stubs. For instance:

```
let(:location) { Location.new }

it "should be invalid with more than 25 blacklisted MACs" do
  location.stub_chain(:blacklisted, :reject, :count) { 26 }
  location.should be_invalid
  location.errors(:base).should include("No more than 25 blacklisted clients allowed per location.")
end
```

Using stubs has its disadvantages--specs are likely to be more brittle, and coupled to the implementation too closely. On the other hand, if you were checking for 25,000 MACs, testing with real objects might not really be feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Haven't used stubs - will read up on it. Am using database cleaner, would the second test have to be in the same block?